# Correlation Id Error on Adding SharePoint framework Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-framework

I'm Adding sharepoint framework Web part (on-permiss). But when Id add it to sharepoint page it gives correlation id error. Attached is the 
[ScreenShot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV6sv.jpg)

this is the exception and message tracked by uls log viewer

> **Using empty subscription Id**
>
> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.    at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s,
>   DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ClientSideComponent.SPClientSideCachedThirdPartyComponentProvider.GetUpdateTimeFromAppCatalog(SPWeb
>   web)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ClientSideComponent.SPClientSideCachedThirdPartyComponentProvider.GetDistributedUpdateTime(Guid
>   tenantId, SPWeb web)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ClientSideComponent.SPClientSideCachedThirdPartyComponentProvider.EnsureCacheIsValid(SPWeb
>   web, Guid tenantId)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ClientSideComponent.SPClientSideCachedThirdPartyComponentProvider.GetNotFoundComponents(SPClientSideComponentQueryResultCollection
>   requests, SPWeb web)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ClientSideComponent.SPClientSideComponentManifestReader.FindComponents(SPClientSideComponentQueryResultCollection
>   queryResults, SPWeb web, SPReliabilityMonitor monitor)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ClientSideComponent.SPClientSideComponentManifestReader.GetClientSideComponentQueryResultCollection(Guid[]
>   componentIds, SPWeb web)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ClientSideComponent.ClientSidePageGenerator.GetManifests(IEnumerable`1
>   manifestIds, SPWeb web)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ClientSideComponent.ClientSidePageGenerator.RenderScript(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, Boolean redirectOnError)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.RenderClientSideWebPartScript(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AjaxDelta.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AjaxDelta.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)     at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SharePointForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)     at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)     at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingCachablePage.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.RenderToBase(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)**

Any Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

You're getting a format exception saying

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

This means that somewhere in your code you're setting a value to a DateTime that isn't valid.

Maybe you have an empty string or have misplaced month, year or day values. Could also be that you're not parsing a string value properly.

Check all places where a DateTime is used and make sure valid values are used. Good luck!

Comment: The problem occurs only if you have SharePoint 2016 FP2 and your site's locale is something else that en-us. The stated issue has been resolved and January 2018 CU should have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same today and found out that this has been issued already in https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1083.

The problem occurs if you have SharePoint 2016 FP2 and your site's locale is something else that en-us.

The stated issue has been resolved and January 2018 CU should have fixed it. I haven't confirmed.

What I did confirm is that if you change the locale of your site to English (United States) from Site Settings > Regional Settings, then the problem goes away. I'm still going to test if my web part functions with other locales after updating to January 2018 CU.

EDIT: I can confirm that after installing January 2018 CU my web part functions on a site with some other locale than English (United States). Tested with German (Germany) which wasn't previously working.

Comment: Yes, your right i also do that and it's working for me